# Code to maximize the sum of squares modulo m

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

Inputs:

```
k-> number of lists
m->modulo
Constraints
1<=k<=7
1<=M<=1000
1<=Magnitude of elements in list<=10*9
1<=Elements in each list<=7
`
```

This snippet of code is responsible for maximizing `(x1^2 + x2^2 + ...) % m` where `x1, x2, ...` are chosen from lists `X1, X2, ...`

```
k,m=map(int,input().split())
Sum=0
s=[]
for _ in range(k):
    s.append(max(map(int,input().split())))
    Sum+=int(s[_])**2
print(Sum%m)
```

So for instance if inputs are :

```
3 1000
2 5 4
3 7 8 9 
5 5 7 8 9 10
```

The output would be 206, owing to selecting highest element in each list, square that element, take the sum and perform modulus operation using `m`

So, it would be `(5^2+9^2+10^2)%1000=206`

If I provide input like,

```
3 998
6 67828645 425092764 242723908 669696211 501122842 438815206
4 625649397 295060482 262686951 815352670
3 100876777 196900030 523615865
```

The expected output is `974`, but I am getting `624`

I would like to know how you would approach this problem or how to correct existing code.

Comment: How did you get 974 as the correct answer?  I'm pretty sure 624 is the correct answer

Comment: 974 is the correct answer if you assume the question means "what is the maximum (sum of squares modulo m)" rather than "what is the (maximum sum of squares) modulo m". See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You have to find max((sum of squares) modulo m). That's not the same as max(sum of squares) modulo m.

It may be that you find a sum of squares that's not in absolute terms as large as possible, but is maximum when you take it modulo m.

For example:

```
m=100
[10, 9],
[10, 5]
```

Here, the maximum sum of squares is 100 + 100 = 200, which is 0 modulo 100. The maximum (sum of squares modulo 100) is (81 + 100) = 182, which is 82 modulo 100.

Given that m is forced to be small, there's an fast dynamic programming solution that runs in O(m * N) time, where N is the total number of items in all the lists.

```
def solve(m, xxs):
    r = [1] + [0] * (m - 1)
    for xs in xxs:
        s = [0] * m
        for i in xrange(m):
            for x in xs:
                xx = (x * x) % m
                s[i] += r[(i - xx) % m]
        r = s
    return max(i for i in xrange(m) if r[i])

m = 998
xxs = [
    [67828645, 425092764, 242723908, 669696211, 501122842, 438815206],
    [625649397, 295060482, 262686951, 815352670],
    [100876777, 196900030, 523615865]]

print solve(m, xxs)
```

This outputs `974` as required.

Comment: This solves the problem, but I would greatful if you can improvise my approach and expound on how I could have solved it

Comment: Sorry, but you started solving the wrong problem (because of the ambiguity in the question) and the code you wrote is irrelevant to solving the right problem. Once you have the right question, the path to the right solution requires thinking of using dynamic programming, and proceeding from there.

Comment: @PaulHankin - +1.  I was initially doubtful of your complexity analysis (I see that there are three nested for loops whereas there are only two terms in your big-Oh expression), but I think your complexity analysis is correct.  However, as is the case with DP solutions, you are using O(M) space!  A problem that has 1e100+7 as the number for modulus would trip the program up.  I wonder if `r` could be written as a `dict` instead of a `list`?

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps the constraint given in the problem is 1<=M<=1000. If M is huge compared to N, this method may not be best and perhaps you can use a sparse representation like a dict rather than a list.

Answer (score 1):

One important **logical problem** here is you have to skip the number of items in each list while find the max element in your for loop. That is, instead of

Example,

```
6 67828645 425092764 242723908 669696211 501122842 438815206
```

and your data is

```
67828645 425092764 242723908 669696211 501122842 438815206
```

That is,

```
input().split()
```

You have to use,

```
input().split()[1:]
```

As pointed by Paul Hankin, you basically need to find max(sum of powers % m)
You have to find the combination from three lists whose sum%m is max.

So, this is basically,

You scan the input, split with space, leaving the first element which is the number of values in each line,you map them to integers. And then, you find the squares and append them to a list `s`. Having that you find the product(itertools module) Example - product([1,2],[3,4,5]) will give, [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]. Now, you can find the sum of each such result % m and find the max value!

That is,

```python
k,m=map(int,input().split())
from itertools import product
s=[]
for _ in range(k):
	s.append(map(lambda x:x**2,map(int,input().split()[1:])))
print(max([sum(i)%m for i in product(*s)]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#dc3NDoIwDAfws3uKXkw2gmSARCXhSQgxE4Y2sI9sI@HFPeOIXj21zb/tb5tS1ShhKeqQorZLoCzzdsZYGRmdUYBBumDM7AGVNS6AdWZY@kB803ZkNA7ugBqc0E9JJ1aTg8@EtVIPdH88C/UYBKz1miRF@odq87pjEbQuhvFspa1fFEV2VLALuAs/lyaexeVtKyHnnJMCKjiTEi5whRuQKo7fNufw1ubUi/4lPw)

This will give you the desired output!

Hope it helps!

Comment: This code is closer to what I have attempted, hence easier to adapt to.Thanks

Comment: If you feel that an solutions posted here solves your problem, kindly accept it so that in future it might help others who face similar issue!

Comment: However, executing the same does not produce the correct answer, could you please confirm the same

Comment: huh! Didn't get the problem statement correctly before. I've added the edits. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. However, if I understand it correctly, you have lists of possible values for f(X1), ..., f(Xn) (probably obtained by applying f to all possible values for X1, ..., Xn), and you want to maximize `f(X1)^2 + ... + f(Xn)^2` ?

If so, your code seems good, I get the same result:

```
lists = [[6, 67828645, 425092764, 242723908, 669696211, 501122842, 438815206],
[4, 625649397, 295060482, 262686951, 815352670],
[3, 100876777, 196900030, 523615865]]
sum = 0
for l in lists:
    sum += max(l)**2
print(sum%998)
```

This print `624`, just like your code. Where are you getting the 974 from ?

Answer (score 0):

Not going to win any codegolf with this but here was my solution:

```
from functools import reduce


def get_input():
    """
    gets input from stdin.
    input format:
    3 1000
    2 5 4
    3 7 8 9
    5 5 7 8 9 10
    """
    k, m = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    lists = []
    for _ in range(k):
        lists.append([int(i) for i in input().split()[1:]])
    return m, k, lists

def maximise(m, k, lists):
    """
    m is the number by which the sum of squares is modulo'd
    k is the number of lists in the list of lists
    lists is the list of lists containing vals to be sum of squared
    maximise aims to maximise S for:
    S = (f(x1) + f(x2)...+ f(xk)) % m
    where:
    f(x) = x**2
    """
    max_value = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y**2, [max(l) for l in lists], 0)
    # check whether the max sum of squares is greater than m
    # if it is the answer has to be the max
    if max_value < m:
        print(max_value)
        return
    results = []
    for product in cartesian_product(lists):
        S = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y**2, product, 0) % m
        if S == m-1:
            print(S)
            return
        results.append(S)

    print(max(results))

def cartesian_product(ll, accum=None):
    """
    all combinations of lists made by combining one element from 
    each list in a list of lists (cartesian product)
    """
    if not accum:
        accum = []
    for i in range(len(ll[0])):
        if len(ll) == 1:
            yield accum + [ll[0][i]]
        else:
            yield from cartesian_product(ll[1:], accum + [ll[0][i]])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    maximise(*get_input())
```